# what is clock-delta in /proc/pid/sched?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, procfs

```
main (xxxxx, #threads: xxxxx)
---------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                      :                 xxxx
se.vruntime                        :                 xxxx
se.sum_exec_runtime                :                 xxxx
se.wait_start                      :                 xxxx
...
policy                             :                 xxxx
prio                               :                 xxxx
clock-delta                        :                   58 <== this one
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was lurking into kernel source to find out what `clock-delta` represent.

I found the function that print it out when `/proc/pid/sched` is read.

It is `proc_sched_show_task` and it is into `kernel/sched/debug.c` file.

Going deeply i found the part of code that printout the `clock-delta`... Here it is:

```
unsigned int this_cpu = raw_smp_processor_id();
u64 t0, t1;

t0 = cpu_clock(this_cpu);
t1 = cpu_clock(this_cpu);
SEQ_printf(m, "%-35s:%21Ld\n",
           "clock-delta", (long long)(t1-t0));
```

`raw_smp_processor_id` returns the id of the CPU running the current thread.

so... `clock-delta` is the difference between two values returned by `cpu_clock()` called twice.

Into `kernel/sched/clock.c` I found the description of this function:

> cpu_clock(i) provides a fast (execution time) high resolution
>   clock with bounded drift between CPUs. The value of cpu_clock(i)   is
>   monotonic for constant i. The timestamp returned is in nanoseconds.